# files are not sorting in C

Tags: arrays, c, file, sorting, metadata

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>

// This program is going to scan all files in the current directory. It will make a tree for every folder
// and the folder will have a subsection of files in the tree format. YES SORTING!

char **word;
int folder[1000];
int filecheck[1000];
int coun = 0;
int e = 0;
int f = 0;
int u = 0;
int p = 20;

void printdir(char *dir, int depth)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat statbuf;

    if((dp = opendir(dir)) == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"cannot open directory: %s\n", dir);
        return;
    }
    
    chdir(dir);
    
    while((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) 
    {
        lstat(entry->d_name,&statbuf);
        
        if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) // Check if it's a directory
        {
            /* Found a directory, but ignore . and .. */
            if(strcmp(".",entry->d_name) == 0 || strcmp("..",entry->d_name) == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            word[coun] = malloc(strlen(entry->d_name) + 1);
            folder[e] = coun; // Mark where the folder is.
            e++;
            f++;
            strcpy(word[coun++], entry->d_name);
            /* Recurse at a new indent level */
            printdir(entry->d_name,depth+1);
            f--;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (f == 0)
            {
                filecheck[u] = coun;
                u++;
            }
            word[coun] = malloc(strlen(entry->d_name) + 1);
            strcpy(word[coun++], entry->d_name);
        }
    }
    chdir("..");
    closedir(dp);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    word = calloc(1000, sizeof(*word));
    printdir(".", 0);
    printf("now, print the words in the order.\n");
    int c = 0;
    int l = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < coun; ++i) // Start readjusting the array in alphabetical order.
    {
        if (i == folder[c]) // If i matches with a folder, then increment and skip sorting.
        {
            c++;
        }
        else // If next is a file, then start the sorting.
        {
            int imin = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < folder[c]; ++j) // Keep sorting until the folder ends.
            {
                char word1[1000], word2[1000];
                strcpy(word1, word[j]);
                strcpy(word2, word[imin]);
                for(int p = 0; word1[p]; p++)
                {
                    word1[p] = tolower(word1[p]);
                }
                for(int p = 0; word2[p]; p++)
                {
                    word2[p] = tolower(word2[p]);
                }
                if (strcmp(word1, word2) < 0)
                {
                    imin = j;
                }
            }
            char *tmp = word[i];
            word[i] = word[imin];
            word[imin] = tmp;
        }
    }
        
    c = 0;
    l = 0;
        
    printf(".\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < coun; ++i) // Print the array in the specified format.
    {
        if (i == folder[c]) // If the folder is the same, print start of the folder.
        {
            printf("- %s\n", word[i]);
            c++;
        }
        else if (i == filecheck[l]) // If it's a file, print the file normally.
        {
            printf("- %s\n", word[i]);
            l++;
        }
        else // Print the file inside the folder.
        {
            printf("  - %s\n", word[i]);
        }
    }
                        
    exit(0);
}
```

My program is supposed to print the current directory in the tree format. It goes through the sorting perfectly fine, except for the final folder it's checking. For some reason, the hw2 works fine, but hw1 does not sort.

```
now, print the words in the order.
.
- hw2
  - find.c
  - ls.c
  - Makefile
  - tree.c
- hw1
  - grep.c
  - factor.c
  - uniq.c
  - monster.c
  - sort.c
- tree.c
- tree
```

I feel like I'm missing something, but I can't find out how to make it work. I've tried different methods and non have worked. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: `printdir()` doesn't actually print anything, and it doesn't use `depth` for anything.

Comment: I think the problem is that there's no `folder[c]` after the last folder. So the inner loop `for (int j = i + 1; j < folder[c]; ++j)` doesn't work for the last folder.

Comment: This whole design seems misguided. You should move the sorting and printing into `printdir()`. It should have a local array for just that directory, rather than putting everything in one big array.